# Unable to build solution showing "There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal" ("<router-outlet></router-outlet>"

Tags: session, bootstrap-4, model, angular7, popupwindow

I'm using angular 7 bootstrap 4. I need to show session time out with model pop up.

Did I write everything fine while running I'm getting below error?

**My app-component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-child-name">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="dialog-child-name" class="modal-title pull-left">You Have Been Idle!</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideChildModal()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         {{idleState}}
        <div class="row mrgbtm">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <button type="button" (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <button type="button" (click)="stay()" class="btn btn-success">Stay</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**and My app-component.ts is **

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { Keepalive } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { AppService } from './shared/services/AppService';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChild('childModal', { static: false }) childModal: ModalDirective;
........
.......
}
```

[image]

kindly requesting u please suggest me the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

import ModalModule.forRoot() in imports array in app.module.ts. Hope it works !